# How would you find the roots to this question?

Tags: limits, roots

I have a homework problem that I arrived.

[image]

With Mathematica, the limit is 0. So by using $\epsilon= 10^{-6}$ (it is -6, not -0, sorry for the cutoff).

$\sin(n^2)/\sqrt{n} <\epsilon =10^{-6}$

So I tried putting that ino Mathematica and no luck so I have a feeling I am approaching this problem the wrong way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\frac{sin(n^{2})}{\sqrt{n}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and the
latter is monotonic so it suffices to find an $N$ s.t $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}<\epsilon$

Comment: How do you know if the sequence $1/\sqrt{n}< \epsilon$ in the first place (the same epsilon)?

Comment: Find such $N$. Hint: find $N$ s.t $\sqrt{N}>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ (why ?)

Comment: You should get $10^{12} = N$

Comment: see my edit to the comment, I had a typo

Comment: and of course $N$ is a natural number, it can't be $10^{-2}$

Comment: No I made a typo, I fixed it. I am still a little confused as to why we can claim $1\sqrt{n} < \epsilon$

Comment: We have $|\sin \theta|\le 1$ for all $\theta$, so if we can make $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\lt \epsilon$, then for sure $\left|\frac{\sin(n^2)}{\sqrt{n}}\right|\lt \epsilon$.